# What is the height of a row in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm in the process of learning bootstrap and am struggling with row heights. Widths seem to be easy in bootstrap since rows typically span the entire window and column widths are explicitly declared.

However the height of rows and columns are much more confusing. So my questions:

What is the default height of a row in bootstrap? Is the row height dependent on the column with largest height? Is there a good way to explicitly define a row height? E.g. Make row height be 50% of container, etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the default height of a row in bootstrap?

The `height` necessary to vertically encapsulate all child elements.
And `width: inherit; max-width: 100vw;`

Container also has no `height`, 
you would have to define one, in order to use `.my-row { height: 50%; }`

**Best practice:** create your own class instead of messing with the css of a bootstrap class.

Comment: So if a child element has a width greater than the column, who wins?

Comment: it overflows. (which you can fix with. `.child { width: 100%; }` or `.parent { overflow: hidden; };`). The best way to go about positioning/sizing, is to use jsfiddle or codepen and try out just the layout. Tackle each problem as simple as you can

Comment: can I hard code the height of a row... say `.row.my-row {  height: 300px}` ?

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik you can use any unit. `px, em, rem, %, vw, vh, vmax, vmin, ex, cm, mm, in, pt, pc`

Answer (score 0):

you can set the height and width of html and body to 100%